# How to use numeric list as a variable input within gsub pattern?

Tags: r, string, gsub

I would like to keep only the first half of every string. The imported data duplicates first names, all in a larger data frame currently:

**fname: TimmyTimmy, PopPop, AdnanAdnan, KobeKobe.**

First idea was to count the characters / 2, then replace that number of characters using gsub, by counting the number of characters I would like to remove from the beginning of each string, using fn_len as my variable in the pattern.

**fn_len: 5, 6, 5, 4**

```
df$fname <- 
    gsub("^[[:alpha:]]{df$fn_len}", "", df$fname)
```

Returns error: invalid regular expression; reason 'Invalid contents of {}'

The code works if I use a single numbers (ex. 1,2,3,4,5) but obviously not understanding some of the patterns rules here.

Alternatively, there might be a better way to do this from the start?

Comment: As a rule, R will interpret anything in between `""`'s as being character data. The `df$fn_len` will not be interpreted/replaced with the variable's value. In this case you'd need to use `paste` or `paste0` or something similar, but it gets complex from there passing this to `gsub` - `substr` is your best bet. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This really seems like a substring operation would be better

```
fname<-c("TimmyTimmy", "PopPop", "AdnanAdnan", "KobeKobe")
substr(fname, 1, nchar(fname)/2)
# [1] "Timmy" "Pop"   "Adnan" "Kobe"
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. That's much more intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

If the pattern is similar to that showed in the example

```
 gsub("([A-Za-z]+)\\1+", "\\1", str1)
 #[1] "Timmy" "Pop"   "Adnan" "Kobe"
```

Or

```
 scan(text=sub('(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])', ' ', str1, perl=TRUE),
                            what='', quiet=TRUE)[c(TRUE, FALSE)]
 #[1] "Timmy" "Pop"   "Adnan" "Kobe"
```

Or

```
 sapply(strsplit(str1, '(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])', perl=TRUE), `[`,1)
 #[1] "Timmy" "Pop"   "Adnan" "Kobe"
```

#### Update

Should work for strings with names that start with `lowercase`

```
  gsub('([A-Za-z]+)\\1+', '\\1', str2)
  #[1] "Timmy" "Pop"   "Adnan" "Kobe"  "tim"
```

#### data

```
 str1 <- c("TimmyTimmy", "PopPop", "AdnanAdnan", "KobeKobe")
 str2 <- c(str1, 'timtim')
```